# Delete pdf files in folders and subfolders with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, delete-file

I try to delete 300 pdf files. All the pdf files as different names, and they all spread in one big folder that divided to a lot of sub folders and sub sub folders. How can I do it with python (I work with python 2.7.8)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree), you can delete directories recursively.

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('/path/to/directory/that/contains/pdfs')
```

If the directory contians other files that is not `pdf` file, use following instead (which use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to traverse the directories recursively, and [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove)/[`os.unlink`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.unlink) to remove the pdf file).

```
import os

for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/path/to/the/directory'):
    for fn in filenames:
        if fn.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
            os.remove(os.path.join(parent, fn))
```

Comment: I think this will delete the directories but what if the contain others files than `.pdf`?

Comment: @Michael9, I updated the answer according to your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is delete just the `pdf` file you can use the `os.walk` function and `fnmatch.fnmatch` function.

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.curdir):
    for file in filenames:
        if fnmatch(file, '*.pdf'):
            os.remove(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.chdir` to change directory. just do some tweak to locate to other directory

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
    import glob
    import os
    directory='/path/folder1/folder2'
    os.chdir(directory)
    files=glob.glob('*.pdf')
    for filename in files:
        os.unlink(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to delete the files while maintainig the subfolders tree, you could use a recursive algorithm:

```
import os

def recursively_remove_files(f):
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        os.unlink(f)
    elif os.path.isdir(f):
        map(recursively_remove_files, [os.path.join(f,fi) for fi in os.listdir(f)])

recursively_remove_files(my_directory)
```